# 2 calls or a single call to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have an action in my .net application that creates a record in 2 differnet sql server tables. What is the best practise here?

Should the one stored procedure create both records?
OR
Should a different stored procedure create each record in applicable database and wrap both calls in a transaction so if one fails, both fail?

Which is the more performant?

Comment: You probably want a transaction anyway.  This is almost certainly premature optimization; do it the way that is cleaner. Run a profiler using both approaches to get real performance stats in your operating environment if you're genuinely curious.

Answer (score 1):

A stored proc will be more performant, definitely.  It will also lead to less code you have to write server-side.  The drawback is, you now need to either know how to write the SQL yourself, or have a DBA whom you work with who can write it for you.

In regards to your other question, it would be 1 stored proc that inserts in both tables.

Another thing to consider:  IF you have to do a ton of things like this throughout your code, it might be worth learning a good ORM and doing this all in code (Option 2).  But if this is sort of a one-off thing you only do in a handful of places, stored proc will be a smarter approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have your logic in stored procedure in SQL Server and define the transaction scope and when this action triggered in .net application does your operation in stored procedure and if this two actions successfully are finished submit the transaction , otherwise this transaction is rolled-back.
Because in this manner you have better performance. using stored procedure according Microsoft documents has some benefits as listed below:

- Execution plan retention and reuse
- Query auto-parameterization
- Encapsulation of business rules and policies
- Application modularization
- Sharing of application logic between applications
- Access to database objects that is both secure and uniform
- Consistent, safe data modification
- Network bandwidth conservation
- Support for automatic execution at system start-up
- Enhanced hardware and software capabilities
- Improved security
- Reduced development cost and increased reliability
- Centralized security, administration, and maintenance for common routines